# Out of memory: Killed process 33831 (Isolated Web Co). Is it a Firefox bug?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, firefox

I have the syslog message after the Firefox Tab crushed:

```
Out of memory: Killed process 33831 (Isolated Web Co) total-vm:2628948kB, anon-rss:52416kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:1864kB, UID:1000 pgtables:1212kB oom_score_adj:100
```

Is it a Firefox bug?

free:

```
free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Память:      7,5Gi       1,5Gi       4,4Gi       626Mi       1,5Gi       5,1Gi
Подкачка:      2,0Gi       1,0Gi       980Mi
```

Comment: It's a memory leak in one of your firefox extensions. Even if you add more swap space it will eventually fill up. `total-vm:2628948kB` is BIG